# What does SetUp do in odoo unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, odoo-13

in odoo there are some examples like this

```py
def setUp(self):
        super(TestClass, self).setUp()
        # write tests here
```

what does this mean because writing the same code in a separate method will give same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the setUp method belongs to Flask framework. So, when you're writing a unit test the setUp() will be called prior to each unit test executing.
Writing a separate function will do the job, yes! but it will run all the tests you gave it whereas the setUp() runs only once for each test.